# QtQuickControls FileDialog Automation

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I'm trying to automate picking a file in QML in a QtQuick Controls FileDialog. How can I invoke FileDialog's `accept` with a specific `fileUrl` when the `fileUrl` property is read only?

The current attempt involves calling `filedialog.clearSelection`, `filedialog.addSelection` and finally `filedialog.accept`. `clearSelection` and `addSelection` are not documented but can be found in https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols/blob/dev/src/dialogs/qquickfiledialog.cpp (Assuming Qt has used a DefaultFileDialog as this can be system dependent)

However clearSelection seems to only work sporadically, having no affect if the same `FileDialog` has been used manually, hence the `addSelection` fails to set `fileUrl`.

The following is a QML file (loaded as a basic project within QtCreator) demonstrates this. with a manual file dialog open button and an automatic one:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

Window {
    visible: true;width: 200;height:200
    FileDialog {id: filedialog; onAccepted: console.log("File Dialog Accepted: ", fileUrl, fileUrls);}
    Row {
        Button {text: "manual"; onClicked: filedialog.open()}
        Button {
            text: "auto_qml"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("Current selection:", filedialog.fileUrl, filedialog.fileUrls)
                filedialog.clearSelection();
                console.log("cleared selection:", filedialog.fileUrl, filedialog.fileUrls) // only clears selection if manual not used
                let t = filedialog.addSelection("file:/home/user/tempfile.txt");
                console.log("add selection success:", t) // a non existent file returns false, so file must exist
                filedialog.accept()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question - what's the point to use `FileDialog` to automate picking file? If I correctly uderstand - you want to ignore dialog as essense and make silence choice. So why do you want to use `FileDialog` then? You can hold chosen file in property and change it dynamically.

Comment: The reason is to improve testing: I want to invoke the `FileDialog` accept during testing instead of what I currently do which is to replicate what it does explicitly in test code. If that `FileDialog is changed my current test code will silently ignore that change.

Answer (score -1):

As variant you can use `Qt.labs.platform 1.1` library. It contains `FileDialog` with a little bit another behavior - `file` property is not read-only.

And you can do like so:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import Qt.labs.platform 1.1

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    FileDialog {id: filedialog; onAccepted: console.log("File Dialog Accepted: ", file, files);}
    Row {
        Button {text: "manual"; onClicked: filedialog.open()}
        Button {
            text: "auto_qml"
            onClicked: {
                filedialog.file = "file:/home/user/tempfile.txt";
                console.log("Current selection:", filedialog.file, filedialog.files)
                filedialog.accepted()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a go. I'd prefer to know why my calls to clearSelection weren't working as expected so I can use the standard FileDialog. Then I won't need to add an extra dependency to labs to my project. But I'm prepared to accept this answer in a pinch.

Comment: @SamBob I might be wrong, but I think the problem is in `acceptSelection` function in [DefaultFileDialog](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols/blob/6.2/src/dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml). The `view` contains the only one index of file - that file you choose in dialog. The silense file ignored because it will never been in `view`.

Comment: @SamBob oh and `clearSelection()` and `addSelection()` are work until you open dialog at once. But use this variant: `filedialog.addSelection(Qt.resolvedUrl("file:///home/user/tempfile.txt"));` cause `addSelection()` is waiting `QUrl` not a `QString`

Comment: I'm afraid this answer doesn't work for me. It suffers from the same issue. Clicking `auto_qml`, then `manual` (to select `file:///home/user/otherfile.txt`), then `auto_qml` prints the messages: `qml: File Dialog Accepted:  file:///home/user/tempfile.txt [file:///home/user/tempfile.txt]; qml: File Dialog Accepted:  file:///home/user/otherfile.txt [file:///home/user/otherfile.txt]; qml: File Dialog Accepted:  file:///home/user/otherfile.txt [file:///home/user/otherfile.txt]`

Comment: Separately, trying `Qt.resolvedUrl` makes no difference as I suspect QML coerces the string to a `QUrl` anyway. This can also be seen by checking the return value of `addSelection` as it was true for success. (And false when a url for a non existent file in string form was provided)